# how to netcat url with parameters?

Tags: linux, http, http-get, netcat

I am trying to do a get via netcat to this address:

```
printf 'GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.iana.org/domains/reserved\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' |   nc www.iana.org/domains/reserved 80
```

I get the error:

```
nc: getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The path should be in the request line (the first line) after the method name (GET in this case). Currently you tell `nc` to look up the hostname `www.iana.org/domains/reserved` which will fail. Also the "Host" header should not include the path, only the hostname.

This should work:

```
printf 'GET /domains/reserved HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.iana.org\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n' | nc www.iana.org 80
```